# Javascript inside Mustache.js template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

I have a list of users coming from back-end and I append each one of them to my HTML page like below. My goal is to have javascript rating system for every user.

```
<head>
<link href="/css/rateyo.css"/>
<script src="/js/rateyo.js"/>

<script type="text/template" id="mustache-template">

{{#user}}
 <li>
  {{name}}
  <div id="rating"></div>
 </li>
{{/user}}
</script>

<script>
$("#rating").rateYo().on("rateyo.set", function (e, data) {
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
 <ul>
  <!-- All the individual users will be in their own li element here -->
 </ul>
</body>
```

Everything is working except my rating script. It should make five stars next to each user. But I heard that you can't put scripts inside templates, is it correct? If I move that `<div id="rating"/>` to somewhere else it works like it's meant and shows the stars.

What should I do? I can't really put that script outside of my templates.

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: This isn't about JavaScript inside the templates, is it? There's no JavaScript in what you posted. It's really about how to get some JavaScript to know that it should act on newly-added parts of the DOM, right? What "rating script" is involved here?

Comment: I left the JS part off because I though that only explanation would work. I edited OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your function to the object you are trying to parse with the template, and then call the function in your template.

```
var userlist = {
        user: [
            {name: 'name nameson', doRating: function() {someOtherFunction();}},
            {name: 'some otherguy', doRating: function() {someOtherFunction();}}
        ]
    };

    var someOtherFunction = function() {
        $("#rating").rateYo().on("rateyo.set", function (e, data) {
            //Do stuff?
        });
    }

    <script type="text/template" id="mustache-template">
        {{#user}}<li>{{name}} <div id="rating"></div></li>{{/user}}{{doRating}};
    </script>
```

Or you could of course calculate the rating on beforehand, and implement some sort of {{user.rating}} and use that to generate in your template.

Or as I look closer, you could just add the listener after mustache is done rendering. Since the div#rating  would then be available (which should really be a class btw).

This would be my approach at least.